# AWS S3 (using localstack - a local AWS version) GET Presigned URL issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, localstack

LocalStack is working perfectly when I want to upload or download an image normally. However, when I try to integrate my download method with [Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html) (Urls with a specific expiration), I get the error:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
   <Message>
      The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
   </Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>test</AWSAccessKeyId>
</Error>
```

This error occurs once I click on the generated URL from my PresignedURL method.

Here is my PresignedURL Method:

```
protected URL generatePresignedURL(String objectKey) {

    // object key example: "Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 11.29.59 PM (3).png"

    S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.create();

    GetObjectRequest objectRequest = buildGetRequest(objectKey);
    GetObjectPresignRequest presignedRequest = buildPresignedGetRequest(objectRequest);

    PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
            presigner.presignGetObject(presignedRequest);

    System.out.println("Presigned URL: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());


    return presignedGetObjectRequest.url();
}


protected GetObjectRequest buildGetRequest(String objectKey) {
    return GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(objectKey)
            .build();
}


protected GetObjectPresignRequest buildPresignedGetRequest(GetObjectRequest objectRequest) {

    // Create a GetObjectPresignRequest from a GetObjectRequest to specify the signature duration
    return GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .getObjectRequest(objectRequest)
            .build();
}
```

Here's my S3 LocalStack config in my Docker Compose YML file:

```
s3-local:
    container_name: "s3-local"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8008:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
      - START_WEB=0
      - DEBUG=0
```

then S3 bucket setup using this command:

```
aws s3 mb s3://$LOCAL_S3_BUCKET_NAME --endpoint-url=$LOCAL_S3_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
```

Do I need any extra configuration to the S3Presigner object? Thank you.

Comment: I believe my presigner method call is trying to connect to the actual AWS and not my Local instance of it.  How do I point the call to localstack?

Comment: Try `S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder().endpointOverride(new URI("http://localhost:4566")).build();` - does that work?

Comment: Do you get the same error? What’s the value of `$_LOCAL_S3_SERVICE_ENDPOINT`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the S3Presigner to point to your LocalStack environment.

```
S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner
        .builder()
        .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8008"))
        .build()
```

You can read the endpoint from a config.

Take into account that in your docker container config, you are exposing the 8080 port instead the default 4566.